# How to change the equation $x y'' + y' +k x y=0$ to an equation with constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem in converting the following ODE to an ODE with constant coefficients.I've tried these substitutions:x=$e^t$ or $y=x u$ or $y x=u$ but none of them has worked.Do you have any idea?
$x y'' + y' +k x y=0$

Comment: For once I'm a bit confused about the down votes. OP asks a somewhat valid question, and mentions some thoughts that were tried (but failed)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should aim at getting constant coefficients, but rather multiply the equation by $x$ and have a look at [Bessel's differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html).